# Nokia S40 Application Development

Tags: nokia, nokia-s40

I am an **Android Developer**. I want to develop apps for my **Nokia c2-00** phone. I dont know anything about nokia application but i am **very interested** to do apps. So friends can any one guide me from where i start reading for applications development and also suggest me important links for the **source codes** as well.

Friends let me clarify

```
1) In which language apps will be developed.
2) which IDE can be used for application development.
3) which database can be used to store data.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think [Java ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/index.html) is a valid option for some kinds of applications targetted at the S40 platform. As an Android developer, you already know Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check here for Series 40 app development:  [http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Series_40/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509001155/http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Series_40/)

Here's about Series 40 Java development tools, for example *Eclipse* : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Tools/

Check also Nokia developer discussion boards and Wiki for additional information

I hope this takes you forward!

**EDIT:**

By now the developer resources have moved to: http://developers.apps.opera.com/

While at first it looks if it was targeted for "Nokia Asha" and "Nokia X" you can still find the "classic" contents, such as:

- Series 40 SDK
- Nokia SDK 1.1 for Java
- Nokia SDK 2.0 for Java

Comment: These links are now broken

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Getting_started/) can provide all the getting started information you may need

Comment: Thanks Gorkem Ercan. I will go through that link